# uploading file using JavaScript - how to get more frequent onprogress events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, jqxhr

I'm using jQuery to upload a photo, and have attached a listener for onprogress events. However even when uploading photos that are a few megabytes, the only onprogress event that gets fired is when its at 100%. I've seen other sites like dropbox and facebook show a much more fluid progress bar. How can I get more frequent updates on the upload progress?

Sample upload Code:

```
var file = $photoFile.get(0).files[0];
var fileBlob = file && file.slice();
var formData = new FormData();
var title = $photoTitle.val();

formData.append('file', fileBlob);
formData.append('title', title);

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/photo/submit',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {
        onprogress: function(ev) {
            console.info('upload progress', ev);
            if (ev.lengthComputable) {
                var percentUploaded = Math.floor(ev.loaded * 100 / ev.total);
                console.info('Uploaded '+percentUploaded+'%');
                // update UI to reflect percentUploaded
            } else {
                console.info('Uploaded '+ev.loaded+' bytes');
                // update UI to reflect bytes uploaded
            }
        }
    }
}).done(function(response) {
    // do stuff
}).fail(function() {
    // handle error
});
```

Comment: Well thanks, this is the progress code I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this borrowing code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) stackoverflow question.

The key mistake I was making was relying on the `onprogress` within the `xhrFields` property of the call to `$.ajax`. Instead, to get more frequent progress updates I passed a custom XMLHttpRequest using the `xhr` property:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/photo/submit',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (myXhr.upload) {
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(ev) {
                if (ev.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentUploaded = Math.floor(ev.loaded * 100 / ev.total);
                    console.info('Uploaded '+percentUploaded+'%');
                    // update UI to reflect percentUploaded
                } else {
                    console.info('Uploaded '+ev.loaded+' bytes');
                    // update UI to reflect bytes uploaded
                }
           }, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    }
}).done(function(response) {
    // do stuff
}).fail(function() {
    // handle error
});
```

Warning: This leverages newer web technologies and doesn't work with older browsers, especially IE.